# Exercise 4.3.4 from Pinter’s book. How to solve it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using Pinter’s text. Ex 4.3.4

4.20Definition[image].

SupposeB⊆A
**prove** that if B has a sup b, then .

λ(v(B))∩v(B)={b}

**Attempted proof**

B is non empty so by 4.34 ,it has a sup or inf.

Suppose b $\in $ B ,for every sup b $\in $
λ(v(B))∩v(B)

Then sup b $\in $λ(v(B)) and sup b $\in$ v(B)

By 4.31 B $\in$ λ(v(B))

<I could go on but I can’t see how I am
going to get {b}>

Help

Answer (score 1):

So $b = \sup B$ is the least element of $\nu (B)$, where
$$\nu (B) = \{ x \in A : x \geq y \,\,\forall y\in B \}$$
We also note that
$$ \lambda ( \nu (B)) = \{ a \in A : a \leq x \mbox{ where } x \geq y \,\,\forall y\in B \}$$
So taking the intersection,
$$ \lambda ( \nu (B)) \cap \nu (B) = \{ a \in A : (a \leq x \mbox{ where } x \geq y \,\,\forall y\in B ) \mbox{ and } (a \geq y \,\,\forall y\in B) \} $$
$$ = \{ a \in A : (a \mbox{ less than all elements of } \nu (B)) \mbox{ and } (a \in \nu (B)) \} $$

From the set definition, we see that the intersection contains all elements that are smaller than those in $\nu (B)$, yet contained in $\nu (B)$.  This is exactly $\sup B$.

Comment: Thanks. So this seems to be a trick question. The proof seems to nothing more than the explanation of theorem itself, in parts.

Comment: I think it is just forcing you to write out the set definitions, like a learning check. Otherwise if you don't write out the set definitions, the answer is not rigorously clear